# Shifting both addplot and tikz coordinates inside pgfplot axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the figure generated by

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{tmp}
  \draw[fill, gray!20] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \input{tmp};
    \addplot coordinates
    { 
    (0, 0)
    (1, 1)
    (1, 0)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I add the keys `xshift` and `yshift` to the axis

```
\begin{axis}[xshift=2,yshift=2]
```

I expect the figure to be shifted, but this fails to happen, why?

An alternative approach I found is to use `scope`, `x filter` and `y filter`:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp}
  \draw[fill, gray!20] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw[red] (0, 0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}] % Putting (2,2) gives the correct shift, why?
        \input{tmp}
    \end{scope}
    \addplot
    [
        x filter/.expression = {x+1},
        y filter/.expression = {y+1}
    ] 
    coordinates
    { 
    (0, 0)
    (1, 1)
    (1, 0)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But to get the rectangle correctly shifted I need `begin{scope}[shift={(2,2)}]`  instead of `begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]`, why?

Comment: Welcome! The absolute coordinates do not have any meaning, in order to shift the axis, you need to shift it relative to something such that the bounding box gets altered and you see the shift.

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me and for answering my question. Can you provide a small example?

Comment: However, your second example is more worrisome. It seems that the `x filter/.expression` has some strange side effects.

Comment: I can only answer the first question: if you add `[xshift=2,yshift=2]` to the axis, you shift the whole thing, so this only means that the bounding box will move, too, and you do not see any effect. You will see an effect if you put something outside the axis, e.g. `... \path (0,0);
  \begin{axis}[xshift=2cm,yshift=2cm] ... `. (Note also that `xshift=2` is interpreted as `xshift=2pt`, whereas `shift={(2,0)}` means shift by twice the unit x vector, so it will be `2cm` in the `tikzpicture` and generally something different in the `axis`.

Comment: It is possible that what you really want to do is expand/set the bounding box relative to the axis, not move the axis relative to the bounding box.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the functionality of `\begin{axis}[shift=...]` and it is different from what I intended to do. My intention is to shift graphs themselves and not the axis. I managed to find a solution for this using Section _TikZ Interoperability_ in _Manual for Package PGFPLOTS_, version 1.16. I move `\begin{scope}[shift=...] \input{tmp} \end{scope}` outside the `axis` environment, use scope on the Tikz input and filters in `addplot`.