# Combining scope shift and addplot filters gives unexpected results

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I get unexpected results when I use shift TikZ content inside and axis environment using `\begin{scope}[shift=...]`. Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}] % Using (1,1) shifts incorrectly, while using (2,2) shifts correctly, why?
      \draw[fill, gray!20] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
    \addplot
    [
        x filter/.expression = {x+1},
        y filter/.expression = {y+1}
    ] 
    coordinates
    { 
    (0, 0)
    (1, 1)
    (1, 0)
    };
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This question is a spin-off from [Shifting both addplot and tikz coordinates inside pgfplot axes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511453/shifting-both-addplot-and-tikz-coordinates-inside-pgfplot-axes?noredirect=1#comment1293425_511453).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default coordinate system of PGFPLOTS is `axis cs`. From [PGFPLOTS manual](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) page 353:

> The result of `axis cs` is always an absolute position inside of an
>   axis.  This means, in particular, that *adding* two points has
>   unexpected effects: the expression `(0,0) ++ (1,0)` is not necessarily
>   the same as `(1,0)`. The background for such unexpected effects is that
>   pgfplots applies a *shifted* linear transformation which moves the
>   origin in order to support its high accuracy and high data range
>   (compare the documentation of disabledatascaling ).
>
> In order to express *relative* positions (or lengths), you need to use
>   `axis direction cs`.

So use `shift={(axis direction cs:1,1)}`. 
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(axis direction cs:1,1)}] 
      \draw[fill, gray!20] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{scope}
    \addplot
    [
        x filter/.expression = {x+1},
        y filter/.expression = {y+1}
    ] 
    coordinates
    { 
    (0, 0)
    (1, 1)
    (1, 0)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```